# will facebook Instagram webhooks notify me of a command deletion?

Tags: comments, instagram, webhooks, facebook-comments, facebook-webhooks

Is it possible via the facebook Instagram webhooks to be notified when a command is deleted? If not, what is the alternative way to know if a comment has been removed from my Instagram page?